# Spring cloud stream - Kafka binder performance

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have the following simple piece of code:

```
    private int i = 0;

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void processMessage(Message<?> message) {
         i++;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    private void scheduled(){
        LOG.info("Messages consumed: " + i);
    }
```

and the following properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=test6
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=testGroup50
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.partitioned=false
```

I have a local kafka topic with a single partition with **96 k messages**. 
The simple kafka consumer provided by the kafka library consumes those messages in roughly **4 seconds**.

However, the above code takes close to **1 minute**!

[image]

Obviously, it is a concern for our application, has anyone experienced this before? Am I missing something here?

Visual VM isn't flagging anything either.

**PS**: I just tried with auto commit and I am still seeing an atrocious performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Marius Bogoevici's research, it was discovered that the poor performance was caused by Mac OS:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/71#issuecomment-263280685

Posting this for reference in case anyone else encounters this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best if you opened a Git Hub issue in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.

Also, can you indicate what version are you using and what is your message size, please, so that we can repeat the measurements? Thanks.

Edit: As per the discussion in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/71, this seems to be specific to macOS (so far reproduced on Sierra and El Capitan) and the 0.9 client)

Comment: I am using version 1.1.0.release. The message size is `payload=byte[723]`.